# Codeigniter view within a view

Tags: php, html, mvc, codeigniter

I'm calling a view into a view. Am I doing correctly, or is this a bad practice?

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_2">
    <div class="portlet ">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                <i class="icon-reorder"></i> Nuevo Usuario
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $this->load->view('modules/user/form_add_user'); ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your controller, a method like this would be best to call all your variables:

```
$data = array(
    "add_user" => $this->load->view('form_add_user'),
    "username" => $username,
    "admin"    => $admin
);
```

(Variables are made up just for example)

Then, within your code, do this:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_2">
    <div class="portlet ">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                <i class="icon-reorder"></i> Nuevo Usuario
            </div>
        </div>
        <?=$add_user;?> <!-- looks cleaner -->
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: form_add_user is a large html form and I placed in another view for that reason.

Comment: Completely re-wrote answer after some research + your comment @AndreFontaine